# C++ Builder Pattern with Inheritance

Tags: c++, c++builder, builder, builder-pattern

I have a class I would like to use the builder pattern on, but it is derived from a base class whose attributes I need to access. I can't access the members of `BaseClass` in my implementation without making them public, even if I derive Builder from `BaseClass` or something equally smelly. My classes:

BaseClass.h:

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected:
        CString name;
}
```

DerivedClass.h:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
    public:
        // builder starts here and has the same base class as the class it is nested in
        // (if it doesn't, we can't get access to name)
        static class Builder : public BaseClass
        {
            public:

                Builder::Builder(CString pName)
                {
                    this->name = pName;
                }

                Builder Builder::Description(CString pDescription)
                {
                    this->description = pDescription;
                    return *this;
                }
        };

    public:
        CString description;
};
```

DerivedClass.cpp:

```
DerivedClass::DerivedClass(Builder builder)
{
    this->name = builder.name; // this is NOT ok
    this->description = builder.description; // this is ok
}
```

My problem is that I can't access `builder.name`. Visual Studio says that "protected member `BaseClass::name` is not accessible through a `DerivedClass::Builder` pointer or object". I've tried fiddling around with making `Builder` a `friend` of `BaseClass`, but to no avail. This [post](https://weblogs.java.net/node/642849) has also provided a workaround, but it's for Java, and very messy.

**Is there a decent way to use the builder pattern with inheritance in C++?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though `Builder` is declared inside of `DerivedClass`, `Builder` is not implicitly friends with `DerivedClass`, like you are expecting.  `Builder` is still its own class, and it follows the same rules as any other class, including scope access rules.  That is why `DerivedClass` cannot access `protected` members of `Builder` by default.  You need to explicitly declare that friendship.

Also, your `Builder::Description()` method will not work as-is because `Builder` does not have a `description` member.  The `this` pointer inside of `Builder` methods still refers to the `Builder` instance, not a `DerivedClass` instance.  If you want the `Builder` to access members of `DerivedClass`, it needs to be given a pointer to a `DerivedClass` instance.  Otherwise, give `Builder` its own `description` member (which it looks like you were attempting to do anyway).

Try this:

BaseClass.h:

```
class BaseClass
{
protected:
    CString name;
};
```

DerivedClass.h:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    class Builder : public BaseClass
    {
    public:
        Builder(const CString &pName)
        {
            this->name = pName;
        }

        Builder& Description(const CString &pDescription)
        {
            this->description = pDescription;
            return *this;
        }

    public:
        CString description; // <-- add this

    friend class DerivedClass; // <-- add this
    };

public:
    DerivedClass(const Builder &builder);

public:
    CString description;
};
```

DerivedClass.cpp:

```
DerivedClass::DerivedClass(const DerivedClass::Builder &builder)
{
    this->name = builder.name; // this is ok now
    this->description = builder.description; // this is ok now
}
```

Comment: The access rules have been updated in C++11. The nested class now has access to all names that the enclosing class can access (see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types)).

Answer (score 3):

Don't attempt to access the member directly.  Use a public accessor method.

Comment: But if the member is only `protected`, shouldn't I be able to access it directly because my `Builder` is derived from the `BaseClass` that the member is stored in?

Comment: I guess I'd just like to know why I have access to the member just fine in the header file, but not in the cpp file.